# Update Password Encrypted by bcrypt MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, bcrypt

I'm creating an admin panel where user can register, login and update his information. While registering user information, I used `bcrypt` library to encrypt and store password in MongoDb. But when I get user information to put it in update form, its giving me a long encrypted password.

I want to show original password so user can see and update password:

Add User Function:

```
// Add USER 
export const addUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      name,
      email,
      password,
      picturePath,
      country,
      role,
    } = req.body;

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = new User({
      name,
      email,
      password: passwordHash,
      picturePath,
      country,
      role
    });
    
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
}
```

Update user:

```
// UPDATE USER 
export const updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const { id, name, email, password, country, picturePath, role } = req.body;

      const Updateuser = await User.updateOne({"_id": id}, {$set: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        country: country,
        password: password,
        picturePath: picturePath,
        role: role
      }});
      
      const user = await User.findById(id);
      
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

      res.status(200).json({token, user});

  } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({message: error.message});
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't get the original password, that's the whole point of hashing (not encrypting) it with bcrypt. Storing passwords is a serious security risk.

Comment: You can't and should not show the user his previous password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashing is one way. You cannot reverse a hash to the original string (nor should you want to, it would defeat the whole point of hashing).
To update a user's password, all you need is the user id and the new password. It could be written as follows:

```
const { id, password } = req.body;
// hash the new password just as you do when you creating a new user
const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { password: passwordHash })
```

This should correctly update your User with the new password, leaving the other fields untouched.

EDIT: Typically, as a mean of additional security, you would authenticate the user again (ask for old password and check it) before updating to the new password.

Comment: this worked for me. But when the user added even 2 digits, its updating the password. I added some conditions also like this in UserModel:
``
password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 5,
        },
``
in React.jsx
`
<Textfield name="newPassword" InputProps={{
                      min: 5,
                      max: 100
                  }} >
`
The condition is not applying. Can you please tell me solution.